# How can we accept multiple values for one command line option in pytest

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pytest

I would want the user to be able to pass multiple values to one command line argument. For example, if the contents of my contest.py has:

```
parser.addoption("--url", action="store")
```

Then I want the user to be able to do this:

```
python -m pytest test_file.py --url "www.example1.com" "www.example2.com"
```

This question is basically how to accept multiple arguments for one option.

Answer (score 1):

You should change action from `store` to `append`

```
parser.addoption('-u', '--url',
    type=str,
    action='append')
```

Comment: but this is not working as expected! Now when I pass something like this python -m pytest test_file.py --url "www.example1.com" "www.example2.com" it gives an error saying "file not found: www.example2.com" unless I remove the space between the two. So if I pass python -m pytest test_file.py --url "www.example1.com""www.example2.com" (without spaces between params) then it actually appends, but as one single string like this: ['www.example1.comwww.example2.com']

Comment: @RajatBhardwaj args = parser.parse_args()

Comment: Can you please elaborate? These are the contents of my contest.py:

`<html><code>def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--url", type=str, action="append")
    parser = addoption(parser)
</code></html>`
and then I use it as this:

'''def pytest_configure(config):
    config = configure(config)
    if config.getoption("url"):
        urls = config.getoption("url")
'''

Answer (score -1):

for me following is working fine

## content of conftest.py

import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "-E",
        action="append",
        metavar="NAME",
        help="only run tests matching the environment NAME.",
    )    #opts, args = parser.parse_args(["-E"])

def pytest_configure(config):
    # register an additional marker
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers", "env(name): mark test to run only on named environment"
    )
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    envnames = [mark.args[0] for mark in item.iter_markers(name="env")]
    if envnames:
        if ( item.config.getoption("-E") is not None )and (not any( x in envnames for x in item.config.getoption("-E")[0].split(",") )):
            pytest.skip("test requires env in {!r}".format(envnames))